# Update Eclipse 3.7 to SR1 (EE Edition)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo

Can someone please help me to find out why I can't update Eclipse so Service Release 1? It has always been nearly impossible for me to make these kind of updates.

I *check for updates* and the only update I see is the Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers (I think version 1.4.1).

After a short moment I get the following error. All errors say *Artifact not found* and I have no idea why this happens.

[image: Eclipse update errors]

Comment: It's almost impossible to read the screenshot. Please post the error message(s) as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Eclipse is configured to query JBoss for updates. First thing I would do is to disable the JBoss update site (actually all update sites other than the Indigo one) and try updating again.